# GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport doesn't add RelativeUrl to ContextUrl

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I'm seeing a localization error when testing a new website functionality in Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0.3 (Java).

We configured for serve this kind of url:
http://localhost:8080/front-web/en/discovery/index.html

- ContextUrl ->  /front-web from front-web.war in Boss
- RelativeUrl -> /en for English

Topology Config

```
PS C:\Users\MTSUser> Get-TtmMapping

CmEnvironmentId     : TridioncmDEV
PublicationId       : tcm:0-41-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Live
WebApplicationId    : TestLive_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /en
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://localhost:8080/front-web/en
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       :
Id                  : Mapping1
ExtensionProperties : {}


PS C:\Users\MTSUser> Get-TtmWebsite

BaseUrls             : {http://localhost:8080, http://frontdev-ecp.frontweb.com}
CdEnvironmentId      : Live
EnvironmentPurpose   : Live
CdEnvironment        :
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : TestLive
ExtensionProperties  : {}

PS C:\Users\MTSUser> Get-TtmWebApplication

ContextUrl           : /front-web
WebsiteId            : TestLive
EnvironmentPurpose   : Live
CdEnvironment        :
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : TestLive_RootWebApp
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

When is trying to get settings.json and _all.json the RelativeUrl is not included to get the file and it's trying to get: 
/front-web/system/blabla.json

Debugging the code I see:

```
http://frontdev-cis.frontweb.com:8083/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://localhost:8080/front-web/en/discovery/index.html')

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" xmlns:data="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" metadata:context="http://frontdev-cis.frontweb.com:8083/client/v4/content.svc/$metadata#PublicationMappings/$entity" xml:base="http://frontdev-cis.frontweb:8083/client/v4/content.svc">
    <id>http://frontdev-cis.frontweb.com:8083/client/v4/content.svc/PublicationMappings(NamespaceId=0,PublicationId=41)</id>
    <title></title>
    <summary></summary>
    <updated>2019-07-02T19:33:42.097Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>SDL OData v4 framework</name>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="PublicationMapping" href="PublicationMappings(NamespaceId=0,PublicationId=41)"></link>
    <category scheme="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/scheme" term="#Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping"></category>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <metadata:properties>
            <data:NamespaceId metadata:type="Int32">0</data:NamespaceId>
            <data:PublicationId metadata:type="Int32">41</data:PublicationId>
            <data:Protocol>http</data:Protocol>
            <data:Domain>localhost</data:Domain>
            <data:Port>8080</data:Port>
            <data:Path>/front-web</data:Path>
            <data:PathScanDepth metadata:type="Int32">100</data:PathScanDepth>
        </metadata:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

I expected that:

```
        <data:Path>/front-web</data:Path>
```

has to be:

```
        <data:Path>/front-web/en</data:Path>
```

Is my assumption correct?

With this response the url for _all.json will be correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution :)

just to refresh CIS configuration executing:

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar forceSync
```

and

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar update
```

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve the issue :)

Comment: Remarkable that fixed the issue! With these commands you synchronize the so-called Capabilities in Discovery Service with what’s in your configuration files. This should not affect the Publication mappings (which are automatically synchronized with Topology Manager).